# Passing socket between multiple client side javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I recently started coding a small web game in javascript. Even more recently, I started refactoring the code to use node.js with socket.io to make the game multiplayer.

My issue, which I cannot find a solution for, is that I would like to pass the client side socket variable to multiple client side javascript files.

In client/app.js:

```
var app = (function() { 
    ...
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        dice.setSocket(socket);
    });
    ...
})();
```

In client/dice.js:

```
var dice = (function() {
    ...
    var gameSocket;
    if (gameSocket) {
        gameSocket.on('dice rolling', function(data) {
            playDiceAnim(data);
        });
    }
    function setSocket(socket) {
        gameSocket = socket;
    }
})();
```

Unfortunately, when the 'dice rolling' event is emitted from the server side, playDiceAnim(data) is never executed. But, I know that the 'dice rolling' event is being received by app.js. For example, if in app.js I put:

```
var app = (function() { 
    ...
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('dice rolling', function() {
        console.log('event received');
    });
    ...
})();
```

Then, the result in the developer tools console is:

```
'event received'
```

The examples that I can find online either put all client side javascript into a script tag in a .html file, or in a single .js file. But, I would like to be more modular than that.

How can I appropriately pass and use the client side socket to other client side files?

[Here is the full code](https://github.com/RylonMcknz/Web-Game). Beware of bugs, it is in the process of being refactored. Also, any aside advice would be greatly appreciated as I am still fairly new to javascript and node.js.

Comment: Well,  you've put the code in dice.js and app.js each in their own closure with no public interface at all so as you have it structured, neither can talk to the other in any way.  You can't share anything the way they are.  For client side code (which doesn't normally have formal modules like node.js does), you either have make a public interface for dice.js so you can call it and share the socket frpm app.js or you need to put the socket in some globally reachable variable.

Comment: Personally, I would probably put some methods on the `app` object and allow the `dice` module to get the connected socket from that interface.  Right now, you return nothing from the closure in the `app` module so that `app` variable is `undefined`.  Why not return an object with some methods on it and then `dice` can call `app.getSocket()`.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! In this post I forgot to show that I am returning some public interface from dice.js. But, it can be seen in the full code link at the bottom of my question. I will definitely try your suggestion. For some reason I thought that wouldn't work, because the dice.js script is loaded before the app.js script.

Comment: You can change the load order to suit your purposes.

Comment: I suppose I could move the client side socket.io connection code from app.js to some new socket.js file which I could load first. That should work. Thanks for helping! If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest:

Load the app script first and have it make the socket available to other callers via a method:

```
var app = (function() { 
    ...
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    return {
        getSocket: function() { return socket;}
    }
    ...
})();

var dice = (function() {
    ...
    var gameSocket = app.getSocket();
    if (gameSocket) {
        gameSocket.on('dice rolling', function(data) {
            playDiceAnim(data);
        });
    }
})();
```

In this case, I think it makes more sense for the `app` to be a provider of services such as a connected webSocket and for other modules to request that information from the app.  But, it really depends upon which module you want to be more generic and not depend upon the other.  It could go either way.